# Can any dragons be solo killed in EverQuest?

Tags: everquest

I've never attacked a dragons. But as I quickly approach some of their levels, I'm wondering if they can be solo-killed. Does `/con` mean anything when it comes to a Dragon? If a dragon cons blue or green, is it possible to solo kill it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dragons can absolutely be solod in EverQuest. The old world dragons were designed to be raided by teams of level 50 characters, but the character level cap has been continually increasing.

[Here is a video of a Tecknoe soloing Lord Nagafen, uploaded in 2006.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=godpodw6ylA)

[Here is a video of Tecknoe soloing Lady Vox, uploaded in 2006.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiC-eZfz1WE)